# Is there a single word for "one who speaks/boasts a lot about everything"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a single word to most aptly describe a person possessing the following "qualities":

- Appears to be superior in every technology/skill under the sun, which he deems worthy of knowing
- On being questioned/assigned the task, is found to have only superficial/no knowledge of the said skill.
- Inherent tendency to "one-up" anyone and everyone - example: "I didn't work hard at all in my undergrad days, but yet I have better/equal grades than you have! "

Could someone help?

**Edit:** I've got some very good responses, but despite popular opinion for "braggart", I'm going with "pretentious" as it suits what I was looking for more aptly IMHO.

Comment: You might want to call them a narcissist as they almost certainly are one though it doesn't necessarily imply the lack of ability. Also see Dunning-Kruger effect for a possible cause of that character flaw http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect

Comment: You seem to have perfectly described what I would consider the stereotypical *nerd*.  We nerds all have to admit that, deep down, we are like this.  The nerd in any given situation who does this best is termed the *alpha nerd* or *silver specs*.

Comment: @snumpy: A true nerd never needs to overstate his ability.

Comment: @Ben Voigt A true nerd never *thinks* he overstates his ability.

Comment: @snumpy: Overstating one's ability without knowing it is a sure sign of a nerd-wannabe.  See Robb's comment above.  True nerds provide the basis for comparison which exposes the wannabe.

Comment: In sweden  we call them "Besserwisser" from the german "Besser" = Better, Wisser = "Knowing"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you may want [*pretentious*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretentious).

Not a single word, but my favourite expression for this sort of person is *all hat and no cattle*.

Comment: The best one according to me - I'll accept it if nothing better comes along !!

Comment: "All mouth and no trousers" is also used in parts of the UK.

Answer (score 43):

Some choices:

- **[know-it-all](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/know-it-all?q=know-it-all)**

  > A person who behaves as if they know everything
- **[braggart](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/braggart?q=braggart)**

  > A person who boasts about their achievements or possessions
- **[blow-hard](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blowhard?q=blow-hard)**

  > A boastful or pompous person

(Definitions from Oxford Dictionaries Online)

Comment: All very good answers, but I was looking for something, I don't know, elegant and less colloquial - for instead, "charlatan" instead of "trickster" :)
Anyway, I'll accept this as answer in a day if no other answers come in !!

Comment: @shan23 - I wouldn't call braggart colloquial, I would consider it along the same lines as charlatan!

Comment: A know-it-all actually knows it all, so he/she isn't actually bragging.

Comment: @shan23 I agree with @Robb - I consider _braggart_ to be elegant and not colloquial at all. Perhaps you mean you're looking for something more diplomatic or tactful?

Comment: @apoorv: The meaning of know-it-all has shifted to a connotation similar to goody-two-shoes and is applied to people who merely _think_ they know-it-all.

Comment: @shan23: Don't feel any pressure to accept this answer if you don't like the word choices :)

Comment: Another +1 for braggart, that word popped into my mind before the page even loaded.

Comment: Reason why I wasn't too keen on braggart - While it implies a boastful/talkative person, it says nothing about lack of abilities to follow it up. A very gifted/intelligent person could be a braggart if he chose to shout about all his abilities...

Comment: +1 for 'braggart', which is the word that came to my mind too. 'know-it-all' seems more specific to *knowledge* rather than *skills*. I think 'blow-hard' should be marked "mainly US" - I've never heard of it in the UK, and i think it could easily be completely misunderstood...

Comment: "Blowhard" fits quite well in the US, though.  +1

Comment: An old girlfriend of mine used to call me a "knowing f**k-it-all", which I've always treasured.

Answer (score 25):

*[Poseur](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poseur)* comes to mind, particularly if that person doesn't live up to the qualities he or she boasts about.

Comment: I do believe that not having the skills claimed was a central part of the question, so *poseur* certainly is apropos.

Comment: I don't know if this is part of what shan had in mind, but this answer has the added advantage of sounding pretty pretentious itself, making it terribly delicious.

Comment: Very apt word... +1

Answer (score 11):

*Egotistical*, perhaps.  It has the right connotations of conceit and excessive boasting.

Answer (score 7):

If you are willing to use popular culture, you can call him *Topper* after the character of that name in the popular comic strip Dilbert. [Here is a link](http://www.jeremyperson.com/dilberts-the-topper/) showing some strips featuring him.

Comment: Stole my answer :P

Comment: That's nothing! I've answered 2900 english.SE questions suggesting to use “one-upper”, and they were all accepted.

Comment: Great link !! I continue to be amazed at the diversity of answers I get at SE... +1 !!

Comment: @shan:Well SE is mostly a techie's forum, and Dilbert is a techie's comic strip.

Answer (score 7):

You could use *mouth*, as in for example:

> She’s all mouth.

Comment: "She's all mouth" will probably be misunderstood.

Comment: What Neil said. I think you might mean "talk"...? "She's all talk" would sound a lot more natural to my ears, and means what I think you intend...

Comment: @kitukwfyer It's a UK idiom based on a [Northern English expression](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_mouth_and_trousers). We use 'all talk' as well - which is probably a little less derogatory

Answer (score 6):

There’s *quacksalver*, which is someone who falsely claims to have certain skills or knowledge (especially, but not limited to, medical knowledge) for personal gain.

Comment: Interesting word - +1

Answer (score 5):

*Narcissistic*

[http://dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/narcissism)

> nar·cis·sism   
>   [nahr-suh-siz-em]
>   –noun
>
> 1.
>   inordinate fascination with oneself; excessive self-love; vanity.
>
> 2.
>   Psychoanalysis . erotic gratification derived from admiration of one's own physical or mental attributes, being a normal condition at the infantile level of personality development.

Answer (score 5):

How‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪ about [*vainglorious*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vainglorious)?

Answer (score 4):

He could be "a phony", or "all talk" (and no action), or "a poser", or "a fraud"; or, if you want to get wordy about it, he "has an overdeveloped sense of self-importance" or he's "too full of himself."  (And if you want to be a bit mean, "clearly he's trying to compensate for something." [meaning, he talks so much about all his other supposed skills in order to cover for his lack of sexual prowess.])

Answer (score 4):

Lots of good choices already, so I'll specialize: in business information technology, the operative word is *consultant*. Your points sum up the general modus operandi for how consultants a) get work without a formal interview process; and b) keep employees on the defensive, or from looking too closely at their credentials.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something that sounds a little more classy than "braggart" (which is an excellent word) you could always try "braggadocio." It's not as good as braggart, but it might fit.

My second choice would be "scaramouche." Scaramouche was the name of a stock character in Italian theatre for a time. In addition to boastfulness, the scaramouche was typically a coward and/or an idiot. Seems to fall in nicely with what you're looking for.

It's also the name of a great book by Rafael Sabatini...Must...plug...the master...:p

Comment: Braggadocio is not a noun in English, however.

Comment: @Marcin Yes it is. Go check a dictionary! :) Still, I agree that it's used less commonly as a noun meaning braggart, but I've heard it done, and it seems it's allowed.

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: scaramouche.... scaramouche? Will you do the fandango?

Answer (score 4):

I like "topper" from Dilbert.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[*Arrogant*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arrogant) or [*conceited*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conceited) may be what you're looking for. Given the description in your question, both seem to apply. I do not believe, however, that there is a single word which would cover both definitions and not be rather impolite.

Comment: An arrogant person need not engage in bragging or one upmanship

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If my audience consisted entirely of Australians and/or New Zealanders, I would use the word [*skite*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skite).  In my opinion, this is the best match for the sort of person you are describing.

If my audience contained people from outside of these two countries, I would have to concur with some of the other answers here, and pick [*braggart*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/braggart) or [*narcissist*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/narcissist).

Answer (score 3):

Consider "**wise guy**," "**wiseacre**," "**wisenheimer**," and "**smart aleck**."

> [**wise guy**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wise+guy?s=t): *Informal*. a cocksure, conceited, and often insolent person; smart aleck: *he has a reputation for being a wise guy*.

"[**highfalutin**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/highfalutin)" might also work in the way of adjectives.

> [**highfalutin**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/highfalutin): seeming or trying to seem great or important; pretentious.

Comment: If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 2):

From the OP's question, I thought I understood that a noun was needed.  So I suggest [Rodomonte.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodomonte)

Comment: [Rodomonte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodomonte) is a specific character.  The derived noun *[rodomontade](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rodomontade#Noun)* is more appropriate.

Comment: @jwpat7 - The OP asked for a name/descriptor for the person, not for what they do.  So I respectfully disagree.

Comment: OP's question asks for “a single word to most aptly describe” a certain kind of person.  It doesn't contain the word *name*.  Although I can imagine the possibility you might be right with your *Rodomonte* suggestion, I find it easier to believe in my *rodomontade* suggestion.  :)

Answer (score 1):

On reading the title I immediately thought of ["braggart"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/braggart#English) but on reading the full question I realized the word that comes closest is ["wanker"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wanker#English).

Of course this may only work in the British Isles, Australia, and New Zealand. And it will have higher levels of rudeness in certain demographics. Bit it's the best word (-:

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *exhibitionist*.

Answer (score 0):

How about *bullshitter.* Though not for formal documents obviously.

Answer (score 0):

"Sciolist", meaning "someone who claims to be knowledgable and well-informed" could work, as could "dilettante", meaning "a person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge", though the former seems more applicable and less subject-specific.

Comment: Got any sources?

Answer (score 0):

How about a "pseudo-intellectual" ?  I heard it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

A **show-off**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/show-off):

> *disapproving*, "a person who shows off (= behaves in a way intended to attract attention that other people often find annoying)" [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/show-off)

A **grandstander**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grandstander?a=british):

> *disapproving*, "someone who acts or speaks in a way that is intended to attract attention and impress people watching" [2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grandstander?a=british)

#### Attribution

[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/show-off) "Grandstander Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed March 25, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grandstander?a=british.

[2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grandstander?a=british) "Grandstander Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed March 25, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grandstander?a=british.