# Someone who appears more of an expert than they are

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I believe there is a term for a person who uses 'expert sounding' terminology and exudes confidence, even when their actual abilities are significantly short of their 'presentation'.

Using 'wine' a subject.... if a person described a taste as:

> Magnificent bouquet, the esters resonate with hints of mulberry and
>   asparagus. This must be an oak-matured red from Bordeaux. Perhaps....
>   2003 vintage, that was a year when unusual rainfall produced an
>   outstanding crop that had the same rich tannins.

A person describing the wine like that has apparent confidence, apparent technical expertise, and so on. Yet, if he was a fraud, and knew nothing about wines, and the "wine" was really vinegar.... what would you call that person? Additionally, this would not be a one-off thing. This would be a person who consistently "bamboozles" people, and only when you dig below the posturing, or put them in the company of a 'real' expert, do you see the reality.

A fraud, a cheat, an imposter. Those would be true, but I'm sure there's a word which also covers the confidence, charisma, and presentation style too.

I just can't think of it.

Comment: "Charlatan" is probably the right word, but "typical expert" comes to mind.

Comment: This question  may already have an answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20103/is-there-a-single-word-for-one-who-speaks-boasts-a-lot-about-everything/182583#182583  and here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203302/is-there-word-for-this-other-than-know-it-all/203305#203305

Comment: Despite being closed as a duplicate, none of the referenced duplicates actually answer this question. The best answer is here. The answer is not "Pseudo-intellectual".

Comment: PhD student perhaps?Typically fine on the theory but lacking experience.

Comment: the word 'eggspurt' springs to mind. That's what we call callers to our helpline if they claim great knowledge in computing, yet display none.

Comment: I’d call him **Dr. Phil**.

Comment: The duplicate is a duplicate of [*One word for someone who thinks they can do anything, and believes everything they do is right but others are wrong*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165899/one-word-for-someone-who-thinks-they-can-do-anything-and-believes-everything-th) which means if someone wanted to give an answer to this question they would have to supply one there. How could *charlatan*, *poser* or *dilettante* possibly fit? Someone should either find a proper duplicate or reopen this question.

Comment: Your 'sommelier' was a **troll**.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My first thought for this would be *[charlatan](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/charlatan)*:-

> A person who makes elaborate, fraudulent, and often voluble claims to
>   skill or knowledge; a quack or fraud. [American Heritage Dictionary via The Free Dictionary]

Another possibility would be *[mountebank](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mountebank)*:-

> a boastful unscrupulous pretender [Merriam-Webster]

Comment: That's it, exactly. And now my brain can stop trying to dredge and trawl... you put me out of my misery.

Comment: I've got to say that both [charlatan](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=charlatan&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccharlatan%3B%2Cc0) and [mountebank](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mountebank&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmountebank%3B%2Cc0) sound more than a bit "affected, dated" to me. As shown by the prevalence trends in those two linked NGrams.

Answer (score 21):

We can call this person a **poseur** or **poser**.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poseur) provides a fairly good explanation of the term, its use, and its etymology.

Pronouncing it as "poser" sounds hip in a surferish subculture way, while pronouncing it as "poseur" (Frenching it up, so to speak) can sound, ironically enough, affected. But appropriate when someone's showing **false pedantry** (not a single word, but a useful and relevant phrase), especially about French wine.

Comment: If I used either word I'd be a poseur.  (Or is it "poser"?)

Comment: "Poser" is a word I may use, but it lacks the sense of "convincingness" that I was looking for. The poseur would not sound right from me, but I do appreciate that too.

Answer (score 9):

A good modifier for various specialists is "armchair".  So in this case, we would have an "armchair enologist".  Most of the other answers I see here cover the ground of someone trying to pass themselves off as a specialist for some separate purpose.  The "armchair" variants, however, rather apply to people making statements with a confidence not proportionate to their actual knowledge.

Most of the answers I see here would apply to a person who would carefully try to evade points of weak knowledge.  Not so the armchair specialist: the absence of knowledge allows his theories to flow unencumbered.  He is not afraid of blowing his cover.

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you might be looking for is a 'Bombast'. If you just want to describe them then the adjective would be 'magniloquent'.

'Charlatan' and 'mountebank' connotate negative intention, which may be undesirable.

Answer (score 4):

The term for this I use is **sciolism**. According to wiktionary.org:

> The practice or an instance of showing opinions on
>   something of which one is ignorant.

And according to merriam-webster.com:

> A superficial show of learning.

The term **sciolist** is typically used within the context of academia where someone gives the impression of being knowledgeable through lots of buzz words but in reality they have a very superficial understanding (at best) of the subject matter.

Comment: This word seems to have been invented for the question; it should be on top.

Answer (score 1):

***Wine*** is a typical subject where some people like to give the impression they have more expertise than is actually the case. That's why it comes first in this list of dozens of...

> [**Bluffers** Guides](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=bluffer%27s%20guides&tag=googhydr-21&index=stripbooks&hvadid=29168085493&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2816469225873985198&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_2nn0q6hppf_b)
>
> [**bluff**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bluff) (verb) *- try to deceive someone as to one’s **abilities** or intentions*

Answer (score 1):

I like **charlatan** as Brian posted above for someone who does this with intent.

However, for someone who's skills or knowledge are merely not as comprehensive as they believe them to to be, **dilettante** best describes them.

> dil·et·tante noun \ˈdi-lə-ˌtänt, -ˌtant; ˌdi-lə-ˈ\ : a person whose
>   interest in an art or in an area of knowledge is not very deep or
>   serious

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilettante)

Comment: Variation: overcommitter/fitter, similar problems. Knowing it can be done, even by skill/intent to deliver, isn't sufficient if infeasible by role or resources. Yes-person seems similar: https://www.americanexpress.com/us/small-business/openforum/articles/7-ways-yes-people-can-destroy-your-business/  . If you exude confidence by accident, or are susceptible to yes-seeking (AoR/feature creep), the other defs are dangerously close without learning and practicing the counteractions: Have an opinion, involve and execute with a plan, detail, produce from research, measure results and check trust.