# What's a word for exaggerations of "worst, best, least, most, etc."?

Tags: hyperbole

I'm trying to recall a word used to describe cases of hyperbole where a speaker refers to a given subject as the ultimate example of something.

For example, President Trump stated, "I am the least racist person you've ever interviewed" to a reporter recently.

Or if a student were to state, "I am the most open-minded person you will ever meet in your entire life."

Thanks!

Comment: Why is _hyperbole_ insufficient? Or are you asking whether there is a special term for hyperbole that only uses superlatives?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! On second thought, could the term 'superlative' be used to imply a sense of exaggeration? Thanks!

Comment: Close enough in my opinion to [Is there a single word for "one who speaks/boasts a lot about everything"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20103/is-there-a-single-word-for-one-who-speaks-boasts-a-lot-about-everything) to be regarded as a duplicate. 'Braggadocio', for instance, is given there. If KarlG's comment is binding, however, then I strongly suspect this is another wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are cases not simply of hyperbole, but of hyperbole applied in a personally boastful way. This used to be described sometimes by the borrowed word 'braggadocio', implying that the bragging and boasting was excessive and flamboyant, and (almost needless to say) beyond any truth -- a meaning that is confirmed e.g. by Merriam Webster, as "empty boasting, arrogant pretension".

Comment: @NigelJ it's a fairly common word, maybe you could google it yourself, or just use this link.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/braggadocio